# Prove that $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+1}$ is biholomorphic from $U:=\mathbb{C}\cap\{\text{Im}z>0\}\setminus i[0,1]\to H:=\mathbb{C}\cap\{\text{Im}z>0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that there is a branch of the square root such that:
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\sqrt{z^2+1},\ f:U:=\mathbb{C}\cap\{\text{Im}z>0\}\setminus i[0,1]\to H:=\mathbb{C}\cap\{\text{Im}z>0\}
\end{equation*}
is biholomorphic.

My trouble is that I get very confused about the codomains. My thinking was to first map $U$ to a set $V$ with the function $z\mapsto z^2$; then map this set $V$ to a new set $W$ by $z\mapsto z+1$ and lastly mapping this set $W$ hopefully to $H$ by $z\mapsto _\alpha \sqrt z$ taking the appropriate branch of the square root. Then by composing the maps in the end, I would get my desired $f$.

The issue is that, as far as I understand, this is wrong: When you look at the first map, you get complex numbers with negative imaginary part by setting the real component of $z$ to a number less than 0 which isn't illegal by the nature of $U$.

That means, in my eyes, that this is the wrong school of thought which quite simply leaves me confused as my last idea is to calculate the inverse function directly and prove bijection by composition. However, the result of this would be inverse function (at least I can't) can't be tuned to the right branch and gets very messy.

So now I am at a dead end and would greatly appreciate any help / new solving method. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your confusion. $z \mapsto z^2 +1$ maps $U$ to the complex plane without the positive real axis: $W = \Bbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$. Now you can define a square root on $W$.

Comment: Yes, but the result wouldn't be $U$ ,would it? As the square root would restrict it something like $\{z\in \mathbb C:0\leq \text{arg}(z)<\pi /2\}$ (not this literally as it would map to $\mathbb C- (-\infty,0]$. Or where am I mistaken?

Comment: $z \mapsto z^2 +1$ maps $U$ to $W$.  Each $z \in W$ can be written as $z = re^{i \phi}$ with $0 < \phi < 2 \pi$. Then $\sqrt z = re^{i \phi/2}$ is in the upper half-plane $H$.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thank you for helping me see it. I guess, I should just train my eye better for these exercises.